# Infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $\phi(n) = \frac{n}{4}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

Do there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $\phi(n) = \dfrac{n}{4}$?

Comment: Do there exist any such?

Comment: There were a few similar questions, having look at them might help you with this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634012/show-that-there-does-not-exist-an-integer-n-in-mathbbn-s-t-phin-fracn, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716805/find-all-n-such-that-phin-n-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There cannot be a single, let alone infinite, such $n$. Suppose that we write $4k = n$. Then we have
$$\phi(4k) = k$$
Let $2^m$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $k$. Then we can write $k = 2^mk'$ where $k'$ is odd. From this we get
$$\phi(4k) = \phi(2^{m+2})\phi(k') = 2^mk'$$
which simplifies into
$$2\phi(k') = k'$$
contradicting the fact that $k'$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

We have the well known formula that 
$$ \frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \prod_{p\mid n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right);$$

from here it is easy to see the equation
$$ \phi(n)=\frac{n}{k}$$

is only solvable for $k\le3$.